# Create dll from existing mfc project

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I have a MFC project which contains many project inside. now i want to make a dll file of this project can anyone provide information how to **create dll from existing mfc project** ?

**EDIT**

I have tried following

- Project Properties > Configuration > General > Configuration Type, should be changed from Application (.exe) to Dynamic Library (.dll)
- Project Properties > Configuration > C\C++ > General > Preprocessor definitions, add _AFXDLL

I have done this for the startup project does it contains all depending projects inside the dll ?

Comment: I see you respond to answers in this question in a very confused way. Please use standard terminology so that we know what you are doing. 1. Don't use the word 'module'. There is no such thing in VC. 2. A 'solution' is a collection of 'projects'. Thus, there is no such thing as a 'project with many project inside'. 3. 'Projects' can output a dll or exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:
1. Right click on "Solution XXX" under Solution Explorer
2. Click "New Project"
3.  dialog is popped out
4. Choose Visual C++ ->MFC -> MFC DLL

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to take multiple projects which output a dll each, and compile them into one dll. If this is correct, then one way would be to add all classes in a solution to just one project. Although i can't see this being a helpful development decision. Why do you want this?

Comment: correct me if im wrong. **you have a visual studios SOLUTION that contains many projects and you want a dll that encompasses all of these projects**. Note, a project cannot contain other projects, it can have references to other projects however.

Comment: Those are references on which my project is dependent

Comment: A dll is the output for a library project and NOT the output for a solution.

Comment: No a dll will not contain dependencies!